# Murphy Chapter 1 Exercise 5

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

[image]

I was able to do (a) and (b). Just stuck on (c). I noticed that this is quiet similar to Theorem 1.3.7. But I'm not sure here if $\sigma(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ is compact here. Also, let $\hat{a}: \Omega(A) \rightarrow \sigma(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$, where $\tau \rightarrow (\tau(a_1), \cdots, \tau(a_n))$. Can we still say that $\ Ran (\hat{a}) = \sigma(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$?

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to say that $Ran (\hat{a}) = \sigma(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality $\sigma(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=\operatorname{Ran}(\hat a)$ is the definition of $\sigma(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$.

As for compactness, $\sigma(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$  is the image of the compact set $\Omega(A)$. So all you need to show that the map $\tau\longmapsto (\tau(a_1),\ldots,\tau(a_n))$ is continuous.

Comment: Is it obvious that the map $\tau\longmapsto (\tau(a_1),\ldots,\tau(a_n))$  continuous because of the Gelfand Representation ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Or can we say that the map is continuous because the map in Theorem 1.3.7 is continuous?

Comment: Yes, you can use 1.3.7 and that the $n$-fold of a continuous function is pointwise continuous.